# When running bin/delayed_job start, postgres has no connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job

When I run `bin/delayed_job start`, I get the following errors:

```
Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=30) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.

PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the following to `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```